# Best way to check if ROS is running

Tags: roslaunch, roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am writing a script, which relies on ROS currently running. I would like to check if ROS is currently running on the script's machine. What's the best way to do this?

A couple ways I am considering are pinging Master URI and checking the processes. However, I'm asking to see if there's a better way. Perhaps an environment variable is set.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10499/best-way-to-check-if-ros-is-running/) by [baalexander](https://answers.ros.org/users/143/baalexander/) on ROS Answers with karma: 233 on 2011-07-06

Post score: 12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want to do it in a script, run a regex over the output of "rostopic list" for "/rosout."  If its not in the output then the roscore is not running.

---

Originally posted by [Nash](https://answers.ros.org/users/130/nash/) with karma: 207 on 2011-07-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [baalexander](https://answers.ros.org/users/143/baalexander/) on 2011-07-07**:
Thanks @Nash. `rostopic list`  does print out an error if roscore is not running, which I can use to check if ROS is running. However, it seems a bit hackish still.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-05-05**:
@Nash thx this works with `rostopic` python API. [My example can be seen here](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_robot_plugins/blob/eb5a4f702b5b5c92b85aaf9055bf6319f42f4249/rqt_moveit/src/rqt_moveit/moveit_widget.py#L251).

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could also use part of [this answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/634/nice-ready-to-use-etcinitdros-script): the following line checks periodically if ros is started.

```
until rostopic list ; do sleep 1; done
```

---

Originally posted by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) with karma: 1620 on 2011-07-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Found this sample in [rostopic](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/0d1d3c9508bf37122288ec1ae446370eb58be6c9/tools/rostopic/src/rostopic/__init__.py#L77). This looks more essential API-wise.

```
try:
    rosgraph.Master('/rostopic').getPid()
except socket.error:
    raise ROSTopicIOException("Unable to communicate with master!")
```

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2015-08-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MarviB16](https://answers.ros.org/users/41101/marvib16/) on 2019-06-11**:
Could this be also used to check if a node is running by specifying the /rostopic ?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In C++ you can check for the master being online, returns true if up, false if not.

```
#include <ros/master.h>
...
ros::master::check();
```

---

Originally posted by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) with karma: 1376 on 2015-08-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 11

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Gives out a boolean if the master uri is online or not

```
import rosgraph
if rosgraph.is_master_online(): # Checks the master uri and results boolean (True or False)
    print 'ROS MASTER is Online'
else:
    print 'ROS MASTER is Offline'
```

---

Originally posted by [murali1842](https://answers.ros.org/users/26540/murali1842/) with karma: 23 on 2018-06-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-11-27**:
Can you please provide an explanation to go along with your code? Code with an explanation is much more valuable than code alone.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you start your script with `roslaunch` files, the best option might be what `ruffsl` suggested on [this github issue](https://github.com/osrf/docker_images/issues/47#issuecomment-277414388) and simply add `--wait` (e.g. `roslaunch --wait robot_plan robot_plan.launch`) to it.

---

Originally posted by [gonzalocasas](https://answers.ros.org/users/34021/gonzalocasas/) with karma: 180 on 2018-08-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2